How to resolve the Composer dependencies conflicts symfony?
I'm writing a PHP application based on Symfony v6.4 and want install a bundle using composer require mybuilder/cronos-bundle
But an error appears:
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - mybuilder/cronos-bundle 4.0.0 requires doctrine/annotations ^1.11 -> satisfiable by doctrine/annotations[1.11.0, ..., 1.14.3].
    - mybuilder/cronos-bundle[v0.8.0, ..., v0.8.5] require mybuilder/cronos 0.8.* -> found mybuilder/cronos[v0.8.0, v0.8.1, v0.8.2] but it conflicts with your root
 composer.json require (^4.0).
    - mybuilder/cronos-bundle[v0.9.1, ..., v0.9.2] require mybuilder/cronos 0.9.* -> found mybuilder/cronos[v0.9.0, v0.9.1] but it conflicts with your root compose
r.json require (^4.0).
    - mybuilder/cronos-bundle[v1.0.0, ..., 1.0.3] require mybuilder/cronos ~1.0 -> found mybuilder/cronos[1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.2, 1.0.3] but it conflicts with your 
root composer.json require (^4.0).
    - mybuilder/cronos-bundle[2.0.0, ..., 2.1.1, 3.0.2, ..., 3.1.0] require mybuilder/cronos ~2.0 -> found mybuilder/cronos[2.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2] but it conflicts wit
h your root composer.json require (^4.0).
    - mybuilder/cronos-bundle[3.1.1, ..., 3.2.0] require mybuilder/cronos ~3.0 -> found mybuilder/cronos[3.0.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.2] but it conflicts with your root compo
ser.json require (^4.0).
    - doctrine/annotations[1.10.3, ..., 1.13.3] require doctrine/lexer 1.* -> found doctrine/lexer[v1.0, ..., 1.2.3] but the package is fixed to 3.0.1 (lock file v
ersion) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - doctrine/annotations[1.14.0, ..., 1.14.3] require doctrine/lexer ^1 || ^2 -> found doctrine/lexer[v1.0, ..., 1.2.3, 2.0.0, 2.1.0, 2.1.1] but the package is f
ixed to 3.0.1 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - Root composer.json requires mybuilder/cronos-bundle * -> satisfiable by mybuilder/cronos-bundle[v0.8.0, ..., v0.9.2, v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.2, 1.0.3, 2.0.0, 2.
0.1, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 3.0.2, ..., 3.2.0, 4.0.0].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require mybuilder/cronos-bundle:*" to figure out if any version is
 installable, or "composer require mybuilder/cronos-bundle:^2.1" if you know which you need.

I'm trying to install composer require mybuilder/cronos, but it didn't help
and composer install\composer update --lock, I'm working on osPanel
composer.json
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.1",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "ext-simplexml": "*",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.12",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.3",
        "doctrine/orm": "^3.1",
        "mybuilder/cronos": "^4.0",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.3",
        "phpstan/phpdoc-parser": "^1.28",
        "symfony/apache-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/asset": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/asset-mapper": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/console": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/doctrine-messenger": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^2.4",
        "symfony/form": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/http-client": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/intl": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/mailer": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/mime": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/notifier": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/process": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/property-access": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/property-info": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/runtime": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/serializer": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/stimulus-bundle": "^2.16",
        "symfony/string": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/translation": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/ux-turbo": "^2.16",
        "symfony/validator": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/web-link": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "6.4.*",
        "twig/extra-bundle": "^2.12|^3.0",
        "twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "php-http/discovery": true,
            "symfony/flex": true,
            "symfony/runtime": true
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php73": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php74": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php80": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php81": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd",
            "importmap:install": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "6.4.*"
        }
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/css-selector": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.57",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^7.0",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "6.4.*"
    }
}


Please keep in mind that doctrine/annotations is about to be phased out. Nowadays, attributes should be used, but mybuilder/cronos-bundle does not support them yet.
Next up, doctrine/annotations in v1 is pretty outdated. It is not compatible with doctrine/lexer in v3, which you have installed as a dependency of doctrine/orm in v3. You would need to downgrade to doctrine/orm v2.14 to find a version that is compatible with doctrine/lexer v1.

After all, downgrading tons of other packages to be able to install this bundle looks like a strange idea to me. There are a lot of other packages that help you run cronjobs in your Symfony application, like shapecode/cron-bundle or rewieer/taskschedulerbundle (disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of the second bundle)

Thank you, but can you please tell me how to automatically launch cron jobs on shapecode??

Waht do you mean by "automatically launch"? If there is anything missing from the documentation of that bundle, report this as an issue on their bug tracker

More precisely, can you please tell me where this is implemented/used?
*/5 * * * * php /path/to/symfony/bin/console shapecode:cron:run

What do you mean by" where this is implemented"? That looks like a common line for crontab to me
